# Calculate half life in days - A tumor is injected with 0.5 grams of Iodine-125, which has a decay rate of 1.15% per day.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> A tumor is injected with 0.5 grams of Iodine-125, which has a decay
> rate of 1.15% per day. To the nearest day, how long will it take for
> half of the Iodine-125 to decay?

I get 99 days, the solution provided by my textbook says about 60 days.

Here's my working:

(Formula for the amount of Iodine remaining after $t$ days (where k is 1-1.15%))
$$A=A_oe^{\frac{ln0.5}{98.85}t}$$

The patient was injected with 0.5 grams so I want to know how long it takes for half of that, 1/4 grams to remain:

$$\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{2}e^{\frac{ln0.5}{98.85}t}$$
$$1=2e^{\frac{ln0.5}{98.85}t}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}=e^{\frac{ln0.5}{98.85}t}$$
$$ln\frac{1}{2}=\frac{ln0.5}{98.85}t$$
$$t=\frac{ln\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{ln\frac{1}{2}}{98.85}}=98.85$$

Where did I go wrong and how can I arrive at 60 days?

Comment: Note that $1.15\%$ is actually another way of writing $0.0115$, so your expression $(1-1.15\%)$ is  $1-0.0115 = 0.9885$, not $98.85$.

Comment: Yep, see that now cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation $A = A_0 e^{\frac{\ln 0.5}{98.85}t}$ is incorrect.

If we start with the general model, $A(t)=A_0e^{kt}$, and use the fact that after one day, $.9885$ of the initial amount remains, we get
$$A_0e^k=.9885A_0$$
So $k=\ln(.9885)$

The model becomes $A(t)=A_0e^{\ln(.9885)\cdot t}$

From there you should be able to get the half-life.

Comment: Just to reinforce this point in my mind - $k$ is always `ln(rate)`? E.g. If I was given a problem where something decays by 50% per time unit then my $k$ would be $ln0.5$?

Comment: Personally, rather than trying to memorize a formula, I suggest setting up the model for each problem, and then using given information to find the needed values.  I think this promotes deeper understanding and is likely less error-prone.